# Can I get File Modification Time from a file open for reading (python)

Tags: python, file, last-modified

Do files opened like `file("foo.txt")` have any info about file modification time?

Basically I want to know if the file has been modified or replaced since a certain time, but if the file is replaced between checking modification time and opening the file, then you have inaccurate information.

How can I be sure?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

@rubayeet: Thanks for the answer (+1), I actually didn't think of that. But... What to do if the modification time has changed? Perhaps I reload the file again. But what if it changes that time? If the file is being touched regularly I could end up in a loop forever! What I really want is a way to just get an open file handle and a modification time to go with it, without a potential infinite loop.

PS The answer you gave was actually plenty good enough for my purposes as the file won't be changed regularly, its general interest on my part now.

**UPDATE 2**

Thinking the previous update through (and experimenting a little) I realize that simply knowing the file modification time at the point the file was opened is not so much use as if the file is modified while reading you can have some or all of the modified data in the stuff you read in, so you'd have to open and read/process the whole file, then check mtime again (as per @rubayeet's answer) to see if you may have stale data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
filepath = '/path/to/file'
modifytime1 = os.path.getmtime(filepath)
fp = open(filepath)
modifytime2 = os.path.getmtime(filepath)
if modifytime1 != modifytime2:
    print "File modified after opening"
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple modtimes you would use:

```
from os.path import getmtime

modtime = getmtime('/file/to/path')
```

If you want something like a callback functionality you could check the inotify bindings for python: [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/).

You essentialy set a watchmanager up, which notifies you in a event-loop if any changes happens in the monitored directory. You register for specific events, like opening a file (which changes the modtime if written to).

If you are interested in an exclusive access to a file, i would point to the [fnctl module](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock), which has some lowlevel and file-locking mechanism on filedescriptors.

Comment: I know how to get the file modification time. That was not the question. And inotify is not guaranteed to tell you about changes under heavy load.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with inotify having difficulties under heavy load? Or point to a source for this statement? There is NO way of being sure, that there is no file-alteration between two file-attribute checks, except an exclusive lock/access to a file! You should look into `fnctl.flock` for this functionality.

Comment: I can't remember where I read this, I'll try and hunt it down, but the logic went as follows: inotify events are asynchronous and have a queue. Items get popped from the queue when an application is notified about them. If the system is very busy the queue can fill up so the kernel will not write any more messages to the queue.

Comment: Found a refernece: `man inotify` and search for `IN_Q_OVERFLOW`

Comment: As for there being no way to be sure, that is fine for my purpose. I'm happy for my program to be fooled by a user/process nobbling file modification times, but I'd rather it wasn't fooled by a heavy load. +1 for bringing up `fnctl.flock`, though it is way overkill for what I'm doing at the moment (as stated in Update 2 its mostly academic interest at this point).

Comment: If you are under heavy load, i don't see an advantage of two consecutive file-acceses over the inotify approach with no file access! And the queque argument doesn't cut it, because in that case it's most likely that your file-systems aren't synced either and you don'T gain anythin from an explicit access!

Comment: The advantage of the two calls to getmtime is that way you get a definitive answer as to whether or not your mtime is accurate (unless someone nobbled the mtime). Not sure what you mean by 'the queue argument doesn't cut it'. The point is whether or not the mtime matches up with the data you are reading from the file - not necessarily making sure you have the latest data (which perhaps I didn't make clear previously).

Comment: Ok, imagine this scenario with 2 Processes modifying the same file: 1) P1:getmtime 2) P1:open 3) P1:getmtime 4) P2:f.write 5) P1:getmtime(1)) == getmtime(3)) evaluates True! Because there is no file-locking the 2nd getmtime is completely irrelevant! It doesn't gain anything! You might even argue, because of the additional 2 LOCs it gets more certain that the file will be modified in the wasted time!

Comment: For the why of "the queque argument doesn't cut it": Either it's an i/o heavy load situation, where you can't be sure of accurate file-synchronizations, it just may hapen, that the I/O scheduler queque modifys your file right after getmtime. In a CPU heavy load situation, your process may be suspended so long, that another task completly rewrites your whole file while you wait to evaluate two old getmtime-values. So with either method (classical getmtime and inotify) your stuck as long you dont flock!

Comment: Neither of those is a problem if you open and read it in between the getmtime calls (as I previously mentioned in Update 2 of question).